# How to isolate the current running commands in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am currently working on SQL Server 2014 and want to know that how can I examine the currently executing statement for each of the requests issued against my SQL Server instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) is a tool in SQL Server that lets you see what commands are processed by the server and other details. It shows all commands from all clients but you can filter them by a number of fields, including the "`Application Name`" field, but you need to specify it in your SQL Server client connection string.

e.g. `Application Name=MyAppName;`

Answer (score 0):

As Dai said, you'll need to use SQL Server Profiler for this. Step by step instructions are available at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047(v=sql.120).aspx